# Type declaration of specific constructor with specific parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this struct:

```
struct A {
    A(int a, bool b):a(a), b(b) {};
    int a;
    bool b;
}
```

Can I somehow declare a type declaration for specific constructor call with specific parameters?

I mean, something like that:

```
typedef A(2, false) A_2_false;
```

So I could use this as follows:

```
const A a_func() { return A_2_false; };
```

- It reminds `std::bind` where you call a function and can pre set some of the variables instead of `std::place_holders`.
- I've tried to use `std::integral_constant` but without any luck.
- I don't want to use `#define`

Thanks

--- UPDATE ---

What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm writing a callback function:
`typedef std::function<const A()> CbFunc`
A simple user should use the `CbFunc` and return `const A`.
I wanted to make things more simplified, so a user callback function could be:

```
const A userCbFunc() {
    ...
    ...
    // Good thing happend
    return A_2_false;
    ...
    ...
    // Bad thing happend
    return A(99, true);
}
```

I wanted to make the `Good thing happened` return type more simplified, so it would be `A_2_false` instead of `A(2, false)`.

Then, I use the struct members when the function returns.

Comment: Btw: Top-level const does not make much sense on return values and is even warned about by some compilers, I think.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe [templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29) are what you are looking for? Another option could be the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a plain function should do the trick:

```
A A_2_false() { return A(2, false); }
```

Usage:

```
A a_func()
{
    return A_2_false();
}
```

Even though this formally requires a couple of copies, all the copies are eligible for copy elision and thus this code can effectively be translated just as well as the original code. C++17 even makes this copy elision mandatory.

You could also make `A_2_false` a static member function of `A` if this makes sense from the point of view of the design of `A`:

```
struct A
{
    static A two_false() { return A(2, false); }

    // ...
};


A a_func()
{
    return A::two_false();
}
```

This is sometimes called the "named constructor" idiom.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a lambda function

```
auto A_2_false = []() { return A(2, false); };
```

and then call it using

```
A myA = A_2_false();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a [lambda](http://ideone.com/8ut9LA):

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A(int a, bool b):a(a), b(b) {};
    int a;
    bool b;
};

auto make_A_default = []
{
    return A(2, false);
};

A a_func()
{
    return make_A_default();
}

int main() 
{
    auto a = a_func();
    a.a = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to make a copy:

```
const A A_2_false(2, false); // a global, reusable instance

A a_func() {
    return A_2_false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 struct A {
    A(int a=2, bool b=true):a(a), b(b) {};
      int a;
      bool b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates might be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <int I, bool B>
struct A {
    int i = I;
    bool b = B;

    static const A construct() { return {I, B}; }
};

int main()
{
    using Type = A<2, false>;

    std::cout << Type::construct().i << std::endl;
    std::cout << Type::construct().b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```